# Slow client transfer-response elapsed time - Azure APIM

Tags: performance, azure-api-management, apim

I have an API being called via Azure APIM. The configuration was mostly default connections during set-up and no customisations or policies added.

There are no errors and I could not figure why it is taking so long. When I run the traces, the transfer-response in the outbound is taking most of the 30 seconds. I am unable to find the root cause and reaching out to the community if anyone has similar experience.

```
      "outbound": [
      {
        "source": "transfer-response",
        "timestamp": "2023-09-21T02:39:38.8147195Z",
        "elapsed": "00:00:29.8959931",
        "data": {
          "message": "Response has been sent to the caller in full"
        }
      }
```

The API is simply used to download a 10mb document from a blob storage. Without the APIM, the download speed is great at less than 5 seconds in all instances. A direct download from the blob storage is also around the same download time. However, if the call is done via the APIM, the download speed becomes significantly high at 30 seconds.